# TexMaker crash Windows

Tags: errors, texmaker, windows

I'm having the following problem (on texmaker windows);

I have a Beamer document and it does no harm when opened.

I also have a different document and this one also does not give any problem when opened.

However when i open both, in the same istance of texmaker, the app crashes randomly while typing, and only when typing.

The app just close without any warning and without saving anything.

Is there a way to have some sort of "crash log" from texmaker?

Does anyone know why could it crash? One of the two document is kind of large (~3500 lines)

Comment: I suggest to contact Texmaker directly: https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/#contact